# How to deal with "This model's maximum context length is 4097 tokens." issue in Scikit-LLM

Tags: python, scikit-learn, large-language-model

I am trying the Scikit-LLM on a StackOverflow question dataset comprising around 7k rows. Below is the code where I train and test a Zero Shot Classifier.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = 
train_test_split(_soQuestions['Body'], _soQuestions['isClosed'], test_size=0.33, random_state=42, stratify=_soQuestions['isClosed'])
#%%
from skllm import ZeroShotGPTClassifier

clf = ZeroShotGPTClassifier(openai_model="gpt-3.5-turbo")
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
labels = clf.predict(X_test)
```

After half an hour, I received the following error. However, I have no idea how to divide the dataset into chunks of proper sizes.

> Could not obtain the completion after 3 retries: `InvalidRequestError :: This model's maximum context length is 4097 tokens. However, your messages resulted in 4438 tokens. Please reduce the length of the messages.`

I appreciate any advice.

Comment: Not a solution, but a hint: You can use OpenAI's `Tokenizer()` (`from tiktoken import Tokenizer`) to count the tokens in your string and check if they exceed the limit. Use it with `pandas`' `apply()` method. This helps you find the row which causes the Error. Then you can inspect row and think of ways to handle it

Comment: @DataJanitor you can count the input, but you can not count the output because you still don't know it, right ?

Comment: @famas23 You raise a good point about the ambiguity of token counts in the error message. The message mentions exceeding the maximum context length, which could include both input and output tokens. However, in this scenario with binary classification, the output should just be a label based on the isClosed column. Assuining it contains something like `"yes"`/`"no"`, `True`/`False` or `0`/`1`, this shouldn't lead to a high output token count?